# Can Google Forms Each submission be one file

Tags: google-drive-api, google-forms

Guys is it possible to get Each Submission of Google form instead of displaying all the submissions in one  spreadsheet it should create a new file for each submission

Comment: You can post process the spreadsheet in any of your programming language to generate files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Google Apps Script to create a trigger for the Form submit event, and then use FormResponse to retrieve the data. You could then construct a file and save into Drive. e.g. CSV/TXT/JSON.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events